# NSUSerDefault not updating my global variable for swift

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

I have a signin/out function for my app. However, I relised that when I logout, something is weird with my global user variable

I have a global variable under my constants.swift

```
var CURRENT_USER_UID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("currentUserUid") as? String
```

However, when I logout from the current user and log a new one in, at the end of the sign in function, I have the following print statement

```
print("Sign in successfully. user.uid = \(user?.uid)")
print("CURRENT_USER_UID = \(CURRENT_USER_UID))")
print("NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(KEY_USER_UID) \(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(KEY_USER_UID))")
```

These prints out

```
Sign in successfully. user.uid = Optional("3P9uavuLtDQZV8ColwTseBIrY4w1")

CURRENT_USER_UID = Optional("hakV4smGyveurPhFN7g9rad4xsP2"))

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("currentUserUid") Optional(3P9uavuLtDQZV8ColwTseBIrY4w1)
```

"hakV4smGyveurPhFN7g9rad4xsP2" was the previous user's userUID.
"3P9uavuLtDQZV8ColwTseBIrY4w1" is the current user's UID which I only just logged in. If working correctly, I would expect all three to be "3P9uavuLtDQZV8ColwTseBIrY4w1"

Does anyone know why my CURRENT_USER_UID does not return the same thing as NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("currentUserUid") ??

Comment: You are set value with same Key then it automatically replace old value and updated the value. http://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/save-data-using-nsuserdefaults-in-swift.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CURRENT_USER_ID` won't reflect the changes happened to the `NSUserDefaults`. The initially assigned value won't change, the value won't be calculated again.

For fixing the issue, Either you should assign the changed user id to `CURRENT_USER_ID` (When that changes), or you can write a global function which returns the user id (I prefer this approach over changing the global variable in your code):

```
func getCurrentUserId() -> String?
{
   return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("currentUserUid") as? String
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I mistakenly think that the NSUserdafault function will be re-called when calling the global variable. Thanks and thank everyone for replying. I did try the synchronise  solution and it got me worried because it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Your global variable is initialised when the app is launched, so it is given the value that `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("currentUserUid")` returns *at that point*.  When user defaults is updated the global isn't magically re-initialised.  You need to update it yourself.

The simple (but wrong) solution is to assign the `uid` value to `CURRENT_USER_ID` when you complete the login and save it to `NSUserDefaults`.

The *right* solution is not to use global variables.  You should encapsulate your user state in an appropriate class and use this to login/logout/obtain the current user.